# Minimise a function of 3 variables.

Tags: calculus, probability, maxima-minima

If I have a function of 3 positive variables, $k$, $m$ and $n$, how can I find what value of $k$ minimises this function (in terms of $m$ and $n$)?

The particular function I'm interested in is this:

$$y = \left(1-e^\frac{-km}{n}\right)^k$$

So I would be looking for an answer in the form of $k = f(n, m)$ which minimises $y$. I just don't know where to start. I've come across this exercise in a data mining/algorithms textbook so I suspect it doesn't require much calculus, but I can't figure out a way to approach this.

I can see that as k increases, $1-e^\frac{-km}{n}$ approaches 1, but we are also raising that quantity to the power $k$.

Comment: WLOG, you can put $a:=m/n$. Then your problem reduces to finding local extrema of the function $y(k)=\left (1-e^{ak}\right )^k$. Finally, it _seems_ that for positive $a$'s there is no minimum. Should we suppose that $m/n<0$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sorry, I forgot to state that k, m and n are all positive. I've edited the question now. They correspond to actual quantities like bits in an array, number of hashing functions etc so they have to be positive. Also yes, I did mean -km/n rather than km/n. I've changed that too.

Comment: The relevant derivative is too hairy, and there is no nice formula for its zero. Judging from the plots  with a range of values of $a=m/n$  it seems to me that the minimun occurs at approximately $k=0.7/a$. I don't know how to justfiy that (and it's too late an hour for me to think about this). May be a suitable approximation gives that?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, that does line up with what I've seen by messing around with this in Python. The minimum seems to come at around k = 0.7 * m/n. I also have no justification for this. Could it be something to do with ln(2)? (I don't know why it would be other than the fact that e is involved!)

Answer (score 2):

$$y = \left(1-\exp(-ak) \right)^k$$

$$\ln y = k \ln (1-\exp(-ak))$$

$$\frac{d\ln y}{dk}=\ln(1-\exp(-ak)) + \frac{k(a\exp(-ak))}{1-\exp(-ak)}=0$$

Let $ak = x$.

We want to solve for $$ \frac{x\exp(-x)}{1-\exp(-x)}=-\ln(1-\exp(-x))$$

$$x\exp(-x)=-\ln(1-\exp(-x))^{1-\exp(-x)}$$

Let $z=1-\exp(-x)$, where $0<z<1$, then we have $$ x=-\ln (1-z)$$

and we want to solve for

$$-(1-z)\ln (1-z)=-z\ln z$$

$$\ln (1-z)^{1-z}=\ln z^z$$

Applying $W$-lambert function, we get $1-z=z$ and hence $z=0.5$.

$$x=\ln 2$$

$$k = \frac{\ln 2}a=\frac{n\ln 2}{m}$$

Comment: Well done! I half suspected that the constant I guessed to be $0.7$ might be $\ln2$, but I thought it was a coincidence :-)